# androidでFileOutputStreamでwriteしてもファイルが生成されない

Tags: android, kotlin

Kotlinでファイル出力を書いています。
動作確認するとエラーは出ず、writeもされているのにファイルが生成されません。

file.createNewFile()

でファイルを先に生成してからwriteしても、ファイルがあるだけで空の状態です。

パーミッションも指定しています(問題があればエラーになると思います)

解決方法がわかる方がいたら教えてください。

```
　　　　　　　　var file = TMP_AUDIO_FILE
    Log.i("TAG", ">>>> "+file.absolutePath)
    val sData = ShortArray(BUFFER_SIZE / 2)

    try {
        var os = openFileOutput(file.absolutePath.replace("/", "¥"), MODE_PRIVATE)
        while (isRecording) {
            var readSize = audioRecord.read(sData, 0, sData.count())
            if (readSize > 0) {
                val bData: ByteArray = short2byte(sData)
                os.write(bData, 0, readSize)
                os.flush()
            }
        }
        audioRecord.stop()
        os.flush()
        os.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Comment: 質問にたいする編集( [リビジョン2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/89493/2) )の意図が解らないので、ロールバックしました。
`replace("/", "¥")` というのは間違いなのかも知れませんが、それを編集で直してしまうというのは、よく解りません。何か理由があるならば、質問者さんに対しても説明が必要だと思います。

Comment: @mjy ご指摘ありがとうございます、私の編集はあくまでフォーマットを整えるのが目的でしたので、replace の部分は意図しない編集ミスです。

Answer (score 1):

`openFileOutput(file.absolutePath.replace("/", "¥"), MODE_PRIVATE)` を`FileOutputStream(file.absoluteFile)` に変更したら書き出されました。